# Tikz: unequal spacing between ticks along y axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to plot a graph with a y-axis with ticks every 100 units. I use tikz. Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,->] (0,2.5) -- (4.5,2.5) node[anchor=north west] {x axis};
\draw[thick,->] (0,2.5) -- (0,6.5) node[anchor=south east] {y axis};
\foreach \y in {300,400,500,600}
    \draw (1pt, 0.01*\y cm) -- (-1pt, 0.01*\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The problem is: the spacing between the ticks appears unequal to me (in particular, 500 and 600 look closer to each other than 400 and 500 do). Note that I also get an error message: ! Dimension too large.

I don't have this problem when I don't divide \y by 100 though.

```
        \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,->] (0,2.5) -- (4.5,2.5) node[anchor=north west] {x axis};
\draw[thick,->] (0,2.5) -- (0,7) node[anchor=south east] {y axis};
\foreach \y in {3,4,5,6}
    \draw (1pt, \y cm) -- (-1pt, \y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), with all relevant packages...

Comment: Why don't you use the built-in graphing engines like `pgfplots` or `datavisualization`? They are built and designed as to avoid problems like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could remove `cm` because the default unit for `y` is `1cm`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,->] (0,2.5) -- (4.5,2.5) node[anchor=north west] {x axis};
\draw[thick,->] (0,2.5) -- (0,6.5) node[anchor=south east] {y axis};
\foreach \y in {300,400,500,600}
    \draw (1pt, 0.01*\y) -- (-1pt, 0.01*\y) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or you use a number before the unit like

```
\foreach \y in {300,400,500,600}
    \draw (1pt, 0.01cm*\y) -- (-1pt, 0.01cm*\y) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};
```

or

```
\foreach \y in {300,400,500,600}
    \draw (1pt, \y*0.01cm) -- (-1pt, \y*0.01cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};
```

or

```
\foreach \y in {300,400,500,600}
    \draw (1pt, 0.01*\y*1cm) -- (-1pt, 0.01*\y*1cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};
```

It is also possible to change the `y` unit for a single path

```
\foreach \y in {300,400,500,600}
    \draw[x=1pt,y=0.01cm] (1, \y) -- (-1, \y) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};
```

or the whole `tikzpicture` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.01cm]
\draw[thick,->] (0,250) -- (4.5,250) node[anchor=north west] {x axis};
\draw[thick,->] (0,250) -- (0,650) node[anchor=south east] {y axis};
\foreach \y in {300,400,500,600}
    \draw[x=1pt] (1, \y) -- (-1, \y) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

My general rule on `\foreach`s is to keep the variable in the `\foreach` as simple as possible, preferably integers, and calculate the more complicated stuff from it.  So in your example, rather than iterating over the label and calculating the coordinate, I would iterate over the coordinate and calculate the label.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/373191/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,->] (0,2.5) -- (4.5,2.5) node[anchor=north west] {\(x\) axis};
\draw[thick,->] (0,2.5) -- (0,6.5) node[anchor=south east] {\(y\) axis};
\foreach[evaluate=\y as \lbl using int(\y*100)] \y in {3,4,5,6}
    \draw (1pt, \y cm) -- (-1pt, \y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\lbl$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note you can also use the syntax `{3,...,6}` for the range which doesn't gain you a lot in this case but can be useful with larger ranges.

[image: Evenly spaced ticks in tikz]

Answer (score 3):

Small variation of your MWE (which have equal distances between ticks):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- + (4.5,0) node[below right] {x axis};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- + (0,6.5) node[above  left] {y axis};
\foreach \y in {300,400,500,600}
    \draw (2pt, \y/100) -- + (-4pt,0) node[left] {$\y$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]